# How can i read a file in php only to a certain character

Tags: php, file

the fseak function sets a cursor to the file but only an offset, a number.  Is there a function or a way i can set the cursor to a text file after reading a character or a string?  Example, lets say i have this text file:

Hi, welcome to your page!

Is there a way i can insert my name for instance, right after the word "Hi" in the text file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the file into a string, manipulate the string, then re-save the string to the file.  If you're running PHP5 you should be able to do this:

```
$str = file_get_contents('filename.txt');
$str = str_replace('Hi', 'Hi Joe', $str);
file_put_contents($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the file contents into a string variable and use PHPs string functions, like `strpos()`, `substr()`, etc. When you're done, write back to the file.

Comment: ya but what if the file is very very large?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `substr_replace`

I'm inserting my string at index 2 and replacing 0 characters.

```
//$data = file_get_contents("file.txt");
$data = "Hi, welcome to your page!";
echo substr_replace($data, " Ilia", 2, 0);
```

this way you don't have to do any string based searches